# Definition of Touch Gestures

Tags: android, ios, touch, gestures

Are there any non-platform specific definitions of touch gestures, that are typically used for devices like Android or iPhone.

I'm trying to write a specification for a multi-platform product that uses touch gestures. However, people have different opinions (depending on the platform they come from) what each gesture means.

So I was wondering if there is any "standard" definition on touch gestures. On Wikipedia [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-touch_gestures) is the best I could find. But I'm sure people who are working on academic UI research must have some standard definitions.

**EDIT:** I just remembered that we have an UX site on StackExchange, so I [asked the question there as well](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7955/definition-on-touch-gestures). Maybe someone can merge those. Not sure what the policy is on cross-posts.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at jQuery Mobile. Their list is not comprehensive, but it's a good start for cross-platform definitions of touch gestures (tap, taphold, swipe, scroll).

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/api/events.html